# Need help doing negative matching in regex and PHP (exclude match if criteria is found)

Tags: php, regex

Hello I'm trying to do negative matching on regex in PHP and I can't get it to work. You can test out the regex below on [Rubular](http://rubular.com) online.

`\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)`

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy7pc2YdrPg">frame</a>

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy7pc2YdrPg
```

What I would like to happen is the first line in the quote not be matched, and the second line in the quote be matched. I would like to search for a `"` character at the end of the youtube URL being matched, to check if the URL is an HTML tag's attribute's value, or is just a piece of text on its own (eg. inside a `<p>` tag as copy). I know how to regex search for if the match ends with `"` (by adding `["]` at the end) but I want to regex search for if the match does *not* end with a `"`

How can I do this?

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow for the answer and I could not get anything to work.

Comment: you can preg_match the content of <a href=" .... "> then use `parse_url`

Comment: 1.- Match A tags URLs. 2.- Remove A tags. 3.- Find matches.